# Core Update: Which Is Safer, Patching or Drush?

Tags: drush, updating, version-control

We have a number of production sites (mostly on one AWS instance) that require an update of Drupal Core from 7.34 to 7.35.

I have tested an update on one development instance using the following drush command:

## drush up drupal

I also have tested an update on another development instance using a patch from this site:
http://fuerstnet.de/en/drupal-upgrade-easier
The commands were:

## patch -p1 --dry-run < drupal-7.34-to-7.35.patch

## patch -p1 < drupal-7.34-to-7.35.patch

There are no db updates involved.

It seems to me that on the one hand, drush backs up the core files but on the other hand, the patch is faster.

So, which would be safer?

Comment: I recommend drush. Because it's easy unless you have hacked core.

Comment: That raises a good point. Due to an issue we have on some sites, we have actually got this patch on bootstrap.inc:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1824360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, by whatever method you use, what you have accomplished is changing the code on your Drupal site.  In theory, both methods you mention should produce the same result.

What I recommend is that you first upgrade and test on a dev machine, and then, once you have tested everything and are convinced that the set of code files that you have is correct, move those exact files to production.  There are a number of ways you can do that.  Some people like to commit all of the files to git, and then use git push / git pull to deploy.  Rsync is another common way to move the code files over.  Then, you just need to run updatedb (unless you determined in testing that there are no updates required), and bring your site back online.

So, in summary, "safer" depends on your deployment plan, not your upgrade technique.

Comment: +1. By the way, Thanks for your Drush contributions. All lives that are now made easier are grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

My website is still "down" (Internal Server Error 500) Because of updating with drush. I have no idea how to solve this, as I have already copied back all the files from the backup and it's still not working.

Comment: Once you run updatedb, you can't go back.  It's really important to test on dev first, because if you mess up your production site, your best recourse is to restore from backup (your own backup of code + database) and start over.  Also, you should ask your own question, rather than try to ask a new question in an answer.

Comment: Actually it is relevant for the question asked. With drush is easy to update, it is good that it makes backup of the files when updating, but, it seems to be messing with some file write permissions, and that might cause problems.